# Close past dates in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, date, fscalendar

I use [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) and i'm trying to **close past dates**, but i or **close** the whole calendar for selecting dates or **open** **all dates** to select.

How i can close only past dates from today's date?

This should be done in this method:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, shouldSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) -> Bool {


}
```

I have found a lot of answers on this subject, but nowhere answer how to write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is you can set minimum date method on **FSCalendarDataSource*

```
func minimumDate(for calendar: FSCalendar) -> Date 
{ 
   return Date() 
}
```